# Alternator gone bad after collision repair

Tags: honda, alternator, accord, body-work

I have a 2011 Honda Accord (92k miles, being driven about 10k/less per year) that was recently involved in a low-speed front-end collision (I rear ended a car in front of me at a stopped signal when starting for a green light). I was driving the car for about a month like that without any problems before getting it to the body shop (could not get an appointment sooner). Coming out of the body shop after a week they took to fix it and drove home couple of miles. The very next day the car stalled in the twice in the middle of the road and after replacing the battery on the 1st incident and had to tow it to the dealership after the 2nd incident found out it was a bad alternator. Could it be possible that body shop screwed up something? The body shop obviously does not want to own up the bad alternator.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Alternators go bad between one start and the next. If the light was not on when you left the bodyshop then it is just councidence. If it was on then you should have seen it and the shop would have seen it.

Comment: It seems unlikely there is a relationship other than the alternator may have been damaged in the accident itself.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! One of the two comments (or both) could easily be answers which should be codified.

Answer (score 0):

Alternators go bad between one start and the next.

If the light was not on when you left the bodyshop then it is just coincidence.

If it was on then you should have seen it when you collected it and the shop would have seen it when they tested the car at the end of their repairs. If this wqas the case then the repair shop will need to sort it.